# How do I sort columns of numerical file data in python

Tags: python, sorting, indexing, graphing

I'm trying to write a piece of code in python to graph some data from a tab separated file with numerical data.

I'm very new to Python so I would appreciate it if any help could be dumbed down a little bit.

Basically, I have this file and I would like to take two columns from it, sort them each in ascending order, and then graph those sorted columns against each other.

[image]

Comment: Post your code as text with your question and not as an image.

Comment: Post also a sample of your data as text also as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not put code as images, since there is a functionality to insert and format here in the editor.

It's as simple as calling `x.sort()` and `y.sort()` since both of them are slices from `data` so that should work fine (assuming they are 1 dimensional arrays).

Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
array = np.random.randint(0,100, size=50)
print(array)
```

Output:

> [89 47  4 10 29 21 91 95 32 12 97 66 59 70 20 20 36 79 23 4]

So if we use the method mentioned before:

```py
print(array.sort())
```

Output:

> [ 4  4 10 12 20 20 21 23 29 32 36 47 59 66 70 79 89 91 95 97]

Easy as that :)